# I met a trouble in MongoDB, help me

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
let user = await User.findOne({name: userInfo.name});
console.log("user is: " + user);
console.log("user's name is: " + user.name);
```

I got a query result for mongodb, and I print it on the console，then I got:

> user is: { _id: 58de51fd5e34037274f790d5,
>     name: 'ygy',
>     password: 'ygy',
>     studentId: '2013302580183',
>     class: '1' }

but when I print user.name, it is:

> user's name is: undefined

but I print typeof user, and I got object.I do not know if the problem is async / await

Comment: print object's keys: `console.log(Object.keys(mongoResult))`

Comment: I have found the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
when I export user's schema,I use es6 module, but I use commonJS to import user's schema.